# How to pass many parameters with aesthetic in React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component with many props (13 props and 9 event handle props) to pass to this component:

```
  <MyComponent 
     prop1={prop1} 
     ...etc... 
     prop13={props13} 

     onEventProps1={handleEventProps1}
     ...etc...
     onEventProps9={handleEventProps9}
  />
```

It doesn't have clean code and maintaining or reading the code is a disaster for me. So what is the most efficient way in my case to improve aesthetic for component props?

Comment: Depends a whole lot on what the props and handlers actually are.

Comment: @AKX  Should a component have multiple props? Eg: >10 props

Comment: Sure, if it needs that many props. Again: depends on what the props and handlers actually are.

Answer (score 1):

First, I strongly suggest you do not pass a lot of props simply because you make things more complex. But if you did that the solution I have is to first create an object. The keys of that Object would be the name of the props you have and the values would be the values you want to pass as your props. and then pass that object to your component. It would be basically something like this:

```
const propObject = {
firstProp: firstValue,
secondProp: secondValue,
...}
<Component {...propObject} />
```

You can use this method to pass your props in a cleaner way.